# Dash pattern for TikZ line, adaptive to line length

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm drawing a bended line with TikZ, say using

```
\draw (0,0) to[out=-45, in=-135] (0,5);
```

Is there a way to define a dash pattern such that the first third of this arc is fully present, the second third is dashed and the last third is invisible? In other words, can the dash pattern somehow depend on the length of the line?

For straight lines, I can imagine a workaround by just splitting the line into three parts, but this is (at least for me) not really possible in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a decoration to get the desired result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
  every curvepart/.style={},
  curvepart/.style n args={3}{
    postaction={black,every curvepart,#1, decorate,
      decoration={curveto,
        pre=moveto, pre length=#2*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength,
        post=moveto, post length=(1-#3)*\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength
  }}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[
    every curvepart/.style={draw,very thick},
    curvepart={solid}{0}{1/3},
    curvepart={dashed}{1/3}{2/3},
  ](0,0) to[out=-45, in=-135](0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw,orange!25,line width=4pt,
    every curvepart/.style={draw,very thick},
    curvepart={solid,purple}{0}{1/3},
    curvepart={dashed,green}{1/3}{2/3},
    curvepart={dotted,blue}{2/3}{1}
  ](0,0) to[out=-45, in=-135](0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw,orange!25,line width=4pt,
    every curvepart/.style={draw,dashed,very thick},
    curvepart={purple}{.1}{.2},
    curvepart={blue}{.5}{.6},
    curvepart={}{.9}{1},
    curvepart={green}{.3}{.4},
    curvepart={orange!80!black}{.7}{.8}
  ](0,0) to[out=-45, in=-135](0,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]